# Solr partial search, strange behaviour

Tags: search, solr, partial

I have strange behaviour of Solr partial search. I use this filter:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20" />
```

I used different versions: Solr 4 and Solr 5.
And I have next results for matching:
1) Word: Notifications

```
Not - YES
Noti - YES
Notif - YES
Notifi - NO
Notific - YES
Notifica - NO
Notificat - NO
Notificati - NO
Notificatio - NO
Notification - YES
Notifications - YES
```

2) Two words: A - Multiplication and B - Multiplicatination (with mistake)

```
Mul: A - YES, B - YES
Mult: A - YES, B - YES
Multi: A - YES, B - YES
Multip: A - YES, B - YES
Multipl: A - YES, B - YES
Multipli: A - NO, B - YES
Multiplic: A - YES, B - YES
Multiplica: A - NO, B - YES
Multiplicat: A - NO, B - YES
Multiplicati: A - NO, B - YES
Multiplicatin: A - NO, B - YES
Multiplicatina: A - NO, B - NO
Multiplicatinat: A - NO, B - NO
Multiplicatinati: A - NO, B - NO
Multiplicatinatio: A - NO, B - NO
Multiplicatination: A - NO, B - YES
Multiplicatio: A - NO, B - NO
Multiplication: A - YES, B - YES (!!!)
```

Why does it work with so strange way? How I can fix it?

Why does "Notific" match to "Notifications", but "Notifi", "Notifica" and "Notificatio" doesn't?
Why does "Multiplica" match to "Multiplicatination", but doesn't to "Multiplication"?
Why does "Multiplication" match to "Multiplicatination"?
How does it work?

I run next query (I fetched it from debugger):

```
/select?q="multiplic"&fq=(ss_search_api_datasource%3A"entity%3Anode"+ss_media_bundle%3A"document")&fq=(ss_search_api_datasource%3A"entity%3Amedia"+ss_node_bundle%3A"task"+ss_node_bundle%3A"supply"+ss_node_bundle%3A"store"+ss_node_bundle%3A"news"+ss_node_bundle%3A"faq")&fq=index_id%3A"search"&fq=hash%3A"8qk984"&rows=3&fl=ss_search_api_id%2Cscore&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=tm_attachment_file%5E1+ts_media_name%5E8+ts_media_file_name%5E2+ts_node_title%5E13+ts_node_body%5E3&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true
```

Used field definition from schema.xml for Solr 5:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal. -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="multiterm">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: you need to show the full definition of the field types and the query url involved

Comment: Persimmonium, how I can import definition what you need? What query I should run?

Comment: paste the full definition of the field(s) you are using, in schema.xml, and the url you are posting to test this.

Comment: I have added info for you to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `SnowballPorterFilterFactory` is creating the problem. Can you check the same by removing it from the index analyzer.

You can find more information about it [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter)